# API versioning with OpenAPI generator

Tags: rest, openapi, openapi-generator

As I found no practical guide online, I guess that a summarized and practical answer would assist many developers out there trying to version their **OpenAPI** specification.

### How I approach API versioning

Ideally, I would like to break my API without forcing clients that are fine with the current version to upgrade their API client package (with `pip install --upgrade` for instance).

The backend and the API client are both generated by OpenAPI generator, according to a `api_v1.yaml` specification file. What I would like to do next is the following:

1. Copy `api_v1.yaml` file to a new `api_v2.yaml` file.
2. Open the `api_v2.yaml` file with a text editor, and add some changes:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  version: 2.0.0  # I change this (was 1.0.0)
servers:
  - url: http://api.example.com/v2  # I change this (was v1)
paths:
    # Here I break the v1 routes with some upgrades
```

Now I have a new `api_v2.yaml` file with backward incompatible changes.

### My Question

I wonder how to use the OpenAPI generator in order to instance a single backend, that supports both of the versions.

The new backend instance should replace the current one, while still offering the `v1` business logic at `http://api.example.com/v1`, in addition to the new changes that are available at `http://api.example.com/v2`.

I will be satisfied with an automation script that does that, but I refuse to manually edit the OpenAPI generator result as ideally this should be done by a `CI/CD` job, once I pushed a new major version.

I would appreciate any practical suggestions, that would also help others achieve API versioning as quick as possible.